# How does jQuery's noConflict function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey, I was just looking at the docs for the noConflict function and it says nothing about how it works (obviously). I just wondered if anyone knew.

Does it unset `$`? (`delete window.$`?)

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js):

```
// Map over the $ in case of overwrite
    _$ = window.$

//....
noConflict: function( deep ) {
        window.$ = _$;

        if ( deep ) {
            window.jQuery = _jQuery;
        }

        return jQuery;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I probably should have thought of that. I am struggling to see how this would work though. Is _$ the kind of backup? And then it puts it back when no conflict is run?

Comment: Yes, _$ is backup of current window.$ var.

Comment: I am getting the code in latest version as



jQuery.noConflict = function( deep ) {
 if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
  window.$ = _$;
 }

 if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
  window.jQuery = _jQuery;
 }

 return jQuery;
};

now deep serves what purpose  ? and "if ( window.$ === jQuery ) " for what use?
"if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) " also for what use? Please explain

Comment: The technique (not your answer!) is inherently flawed: what if `_$` exists?  Should use a guid instead, when the odds of a collision are infinitesimal, but you can always check for that too

Answer (score 9):

It reverts `$` to what it was before jQuery was loaded.

Comment: Ah right, that answers my question on Distdev's answer. I want to accept both of your answers really :/